# How to remove a blank line in python

Tags: python

This is my code for a times table:

```
Y=int(input(""))
X=int(input(""))

for i in range(1,Y+1):
    print("")
    for j in range(1,X+1):
        print("{:>4}".format(str(i*j)),end="")
```

This is the output when X=3 and Y=2:

```
   1   2
   2   4
   3   6
```

The output is correct but there is an extra spacing at the top that i need to get rid of.

```
   1   2
   2   4
   3   6
```

This is what i would like to get. Can anyone please help with this problem.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the empty `print` at the end, and no need of `""` into it, also no need to cast as `str`

```
for i in range(1,Y+1):
    for j in range(1,X+1):
        print("{:>4}".format(i*j),end="")
    print()
```

You can also concat the inner loop, like

```
for i in range(1,Y+1):
    val = ""
    for j in range(1,X+1):
         val+= "{:>4}".format(i*j)
    print(val)
```

Or shorter

```
for i in range(1, Y + 1):
    print("".join(map(lambda j: "{:>4}".format(i * j), range(1, X + 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is perfect.

Comment: @Ylpir just add another shortest one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
Y = int(input(""))
X = int(input(""))
for i in range(1, Y + 1):
    if i > 1:
        print()
    for j in range(1, X + 1):
        print("{:>4}".format(str(i * j)), end="")
```

OR

```
    Y = int(input(""))
    X = int(input(""))
    for i in range(1, Y + 1):
        for j in range(1, X + 1):
            print("{:>4}".format(str(i * j)), end="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `print("")` line to the bottom, but keep the same indentation:

```
y = int(input("y: "))
x = int(input("x: "))

for i in range(1, y+1):
    for j in range(1, x+1):
        print("{:>4}".format(i*j), end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,Y+1):
    for j in range(1,X+1):
        print("{:>4}".format(str(i*j)),end="")
    print("")
```